# How to pass an interface to a constructor in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, interface, constructor

I am trying to convert some code from c# to vb.net.  The whole code is in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474418/DataGridViewplus-e2-80-93plusStackedplusHeader.  I almost have it but I am running into a problem with the constructor.  In C# it is passing in an interface.  Like the following

```
    public StackedHeaderDecorator(IStackedHeaderGenerator objStackedHeaderGenerator, DataGridView objDataGrid)
        : this(objDataGrid)
    {
        this.objStackedHeaderGenerator = objStackedHeaderGenerator;
    }
```

I am not sure how to convert this to vb.net.  I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me how to write the code to pass an integerface to a constructor.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: refering to your comment to @DStanley's answer, please show the class declaration of your VB.Net class?

Answer (score 4):

You pass an interface reference just like you'd pass any type:

```
Sub New(objStackedHeaderGenerator As IStackedHeaderGenerator, objDataGrid As DataGridView)

    Me.New(objDataGrid)

    Me.objStackedHeaderGenerator = objStackedHeaderGenerator

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I try that and get the following error message: 'objStackedHeaderGenerator' cannot expose type 'IStackedHeadeGenerator' outside the project through class 'StackedHeaderDecorator'

Comment: @GregoryWilliams that is important information that you should add to your question!

Comment: My guess is that the class this constructor belongs to is marked Public while IStackedHeaderGenerator is marked Friend/Private/Protected. This would imply that IStackedHeaderGenerator is public too which it isn't which is what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90htzsex.aspx) is the documentation on that issue.  It sounds like that interface is private, but without seeing the source it's hard to tell.  As @jeroenh suggests that would make a good follow-up question.  After you do some research of course :)